# Was this scene in S8E06 added because of fan reactions to S8E04?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S8E04, fans were very upset after Jon Snow was reunited with his direwolf, Ghost, but seemed to ignore him.

Here are just a few reactions:

- Vox: [Why Game of Thrones fans are outraged over the show’s treatment of [spoiler]](https://www.vox.com/2019/5/6/18531170/game-of-thrones-is-ghost-alive-what-happened-to-jon-snows-direwolf)
- Harper's Bazaar: [Jon Snow Didn't Even [spoiler] in Game of Thrones Tonight](https://www.harpersbazaar.com/culture/film-tv/a27369756/jon-snow-ghost-goodbye-game-of-thrones/)
- Buzzfeed: [People Are Very Unhappy With Jon Snow After "Game Of Thrones" Season 8, Episode 4](https://www.buzzfeed.com/crystalro/game-of-thrones-ghost-season-8)

Then in S8E06, Jon saw Ghost again at Castle Black and showed him affection.

Was this very short scene edited in due to fan outrage over previous episodes in the season? It lasts only a few seconds, and I don't remember a prior instance of *anyone* touching a direwolf in the shows, aside from when they were first found.

Comment: We sometimes tend to forget that these things have been filmed *looong* before they're aired. They hardly could have added this scene in a matter of days even if they wanted to. (I guess. there *could* still be the possibility they cut it and then reedited it in if it was only a few seconds.) But maybe for once the show got something right *on its own* without the "help" of enraged fans. ;-)

Comment: My first thought on seeing that scene was that it was *dodgy*. Watch the way Jon pats and ducks from Ghost. Maybe it wasn’t shot and rendered in a week, but could it have been a rejected take or deleted scene that was spliced in last minute?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, didn't they remove the coffee cup as soon as it was spotted?  Seems like they could throw in a scene that was previously cut just as easily.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As mentioned by Napoleon Wilson perfectly "We sometimes tend to forget that these things have been filmed looong before they're aired. They hardly could have added this scene in a matter of days even if they wanted to".

To add more to it from [vox](https://www.vox.com/2019/5/20/18632128/game-of-thrones-finale-did-ghost-die-what-happened)

> David Benioff and D.B. Weiss must have been laughing to themselves so hard when we freaked out a couple weeks ago about Jon Snow not petting Ghost goodbye when leaving the north. There has to have been some "Oh, just wait for it, you whiners" in there somewhere. - Tasha Robinson (The Verge)

And show like Game of Thrones can't do a reshoot this late for a high CGI required Direwolf scene.

Even the episode director (David Nutter) explained why the goodbye was not as fan wanted:

> “Since the direwolves are kind of CG creations, we felt it
>   best to keep it as simple as possible,” said Nutter. “And I think that
>   it played out much more powerfully that way.”
>
> “Keeping Ghost off to the side, I thought that played out better,” he
>   added.

So how can they do a costly shot in so short interval? So my common-sense say no, not possible.

Comment: Replying to the stupid Verge article: Except Jon wouldn't have known he was coming back, so it's still absurd he didn't pet him goodbye.

Comment: @spacetyper they saved money on goodbye scene

Comment: @spacetyper Or he didn't pet him exactly because he thought he isn't coming back. You can see E6 as "I'm back now, and I'm not leaving again".

Answer (score 16):

## No

Joe Bauer the visual effects supervisor has said the below stating that Ghost is very present in Season 8, seeing as he wasn't we can assume that once again his scenes were cut so this was likely in from the start.

> Yes, Ghost will return—and not just for a tiny cameo. “Oh, you’ll see him again. He has a fair amount of screen time in Season 8,” Bauer said. “He does show up. . . . He’s very present and does some pretty cool things.” Bauer also noted that in addition to budgetary concerns, the show has sidestepped the wolves because it can be difficult to make supersized wolves look natural and non-cartoonish: “The direwolves are tough, because you don’t want to get them wrong. So we end up always shooting real wolves and doing a scaling trick with them. But the real wolves only behave in certain ways. I think that has something to do with why the direwolves are in the show, but they’re not maybe as integral as they are in the books.” Basically, this has been the Thrones approach to direwolves for the past few seasons.
>
> <sub>[Vanity Fair, Game of Thrones: What Ghost’s Season 8 Return Could Mean for the Endgame](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/10/game-of-thrones-season-8-ghost-direwolf-returning-nymeria-battle-ending)</sub>